# Get value in mutli array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would i get the value of a key in an array?

The array is done by google shopping api which is:

```
// Valid source values are "public", "cx:cse", and "gan:pid"
// See http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html#products-feed
$source = "public";

// For more information about full text search with the shopping API, please
// see http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html#text-search
$query = "\"mp3 player\" | ipod";

//The order in which the API returns products is defined by a ranking criterion.
// See http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html#ranking
$ranking = "relevancy";

$results = $service->products->listProducts($source, array(
  "country" => "UK",
  "q" => $query,
  "rankBy" => $ranking,
));

print "<h1>Shopping Results</h1><pre>" . print_r($results, true) . "</pre>";
```

I have the following array which outputs:
Shopping Results

```
Array
(
    [kind] => shopping#products
    [etag] => "*********"
    [id] => tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products
    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?country=UK&q=iphone&rankBy=relevancy
    [nextLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?country=UK&q=iphone&rankBy=relevancy&startIndex=26
    [totalItems] => 771622
    [startIndex] => 1
    [itemsPerPage] => 25
    [currentItemCount] => 25
    [requestId] => 0CMjH976CqbECFYNWtAodLRwAAA
    [items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [kind] => shopping#product
                [id] => tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/5735617/11254757413841304510
                [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/5735617/gid/11254757413841304510
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [googleId] => 11254757413841304510
                        [author] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Amazon.co.uk
                                [accountId] => 5735617
                            )

                        [creationTime] => 2012-05-04T05:03:50.000Z
                        [modificationTime] => 2012-07-20T02:02:16.000Z
                        [country] => GB
                        [language] => en
                        [title] => Apple iPod touch 8GB - Black - 4th Generation (Latest Model - Launched Sept 2010)
                        [description] => Apple iPod touch 8GB - Black - 4th Generation (Latest Model - Launched Sept 2010)
                        [link] => http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0040GIZTI/ref=asc_df_B0040GIZTI8843997?smid=A1YZ4RXO7GUOYN&tag=googlecouk06-21&linkCode=asn&creative=22218&creativeASIN=B0040GIZTI
                        [brand] => Apple
                        [condition] => new
                        [gtin] => 00885909394739
                        [gtins] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 00885909394739
                            )

                        [mpns] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => MC540BT/A
                            )

                        [inventories] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [channel] => online
                                        [availability] => inStock
                                        [price] => 135.95
                                        [shipping] => 1.99
                                        [currency] => GBP
                                    )

                            )

                        [images] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [link] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41p2rNmazRL.jpg
                                        [status] => available
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [kind] => shopping#product
                [id] => tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/5735617/4597224105326146239
                [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/5735617/gid/4597224105326146239
                [product] => Array
                    (
                        [googleId] => 4597224105326146239
                        [author] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Amazon.co.uk
                                [accountId] => 5735617
                            )

                        [creationTime] => 2012-05-04T05:03:50.000Z
                        [modificationTime] => 2012-07-20T02:02:16.000Z
                        [country] => GB
                        [language] => en
                        [title] => SanDisk Sansa Clip+ 8GB MP3 Player with Radio and Expandable MicroSD/SDHC Slot - Black
                        [description] => 8 GB memory Digital FM-tuner with 40 preset radio stations Extendable microSD/microSDHC card slot
                        [link] => http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002NX0ME6/ref=asc_df_B002NX0ME68843997?smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&tag=googlecouk06-21&linkCode=asn&creative=22206&creativeASIN=B002NX0ME6
                        [brand] => SanDisk
                        [condition] => new
                        [gtin] => 00619659059989
                        [gtins] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 00619659059989
                            )

                        [mpns] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SDMX18-008G-E46K
                            )

                        [inventories] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [channel] => online
                                        [availability] => inStock
                                        [price] => 46.95
                                        [shipping] => 0
                                        [currency] => GBP
                                    )

                            )

                        [images] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [link] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/419U6bYDF1L.jpg
                                        [status] => available
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

I don't need all this data i just need 3-4 of the keys but how would i access them? How would i echo the value of say [title] from each array?

Comment: Ok i fixed it. Solution was:

    foreach ($results['items'] as $result) {
        echo $result['product']['title'];
    }

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foreach( $results as $result)
    foreach( $result['product'] as $product) 
        echo $product['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either loop through the array like pointed out above or possibly use array_walk_recursive like this:

```
$title_array = array();

array_walk_recursive($input_array, 'find_titles');

function find_titles($value, $key) {
    global $title_array;
    if ($key == 'title') {
        $title_array[] = $value;
    }
}
```

This might be a better solution if you you are not certain what the structure of the input array will be (i.e. how many levels deep the key you are looking for is nested).

Answer (score 0):

To output the title of each product in $results:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['product']['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Working example

```
<?php
$a = array("hai", array("ha"=>1, "hai"=>2, array("a"=>1, "b"=>2)));
function test($item, $key) 
{
     echo "$key holds $item\n";
}
array_walk_recursive($a, 'test');

0 holds hai
ha holds 1
hai holds 2
a holds 1
b holds 2
```

If you are interested only in title

Consider using [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($results['item'] as $result) {
   echo $result['product']['title'];
}
```

Comment: that throws a Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in

Comment: @MarkGodley I din't notice the item array sorry. I hope this should fix the issue

Comment: @MarkGodley Didn't notice your comment in the OP